# Microsoft Word: List of Tables and Figures - Titles in bold, numbers/separators regular

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am managing a document with around 100 figures and 50 tables, and as such relying on the built in table/figure list feature in Microsoft Word. To clarify, this is "Insert Table of Figures" feature in the References ribbon.

I want to have the figure and table titles listed in bold font, and page numbers and seperators (i.e. '.....' interspersing titles and right aligned page numbers) in regular.

The formatting options I can find seem to be all or nothing - that is I can bold all text, or no text at all. I initially went through manually bolding all of the entries, but any time there is a reference update (page print, manual refresh, title change) it all reverts!

For what it's worth my Fig/Tab titles are in the same defined style - but also can't seem to find an option to integrate that into my table.

I am working on Office 2016 on both Windows and OSX - happy to take directions on either!

Answer (score 0):

See Word MVP Suzanne Barhill's Article on [TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#DirectFormatting) - in particular the section on how the TOC looks - Direct Formatting.

### A Table of Figures is a variant of a Table of Contents. Both use the TOC field.

You want the source to have Direct formatting of **Bold**, not the underlying paragraph (caption) style but either a character style applied to the text or the **Bold** format applied to the text that is captured to make up the entry.

That way, if you want Bold formatting for the text of the TOF entry, you will get it and the page numbers will not be formatted Bold. Or, if your TOF style has Bold formattinng, that will toggle off the Bold from the source text and only the page numbers (and dot leaders) will be Bold.

Here is a link to my writing on [Creating a Table of Figures in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures).

Answer (score -1):

Word allows you to modify table styles quite easily.

In the Table Tools contextual ribbon, in the Table Styles section, click the button that shows all available table styles.

At the bottom of this is the "Modify Table Style..." or "New Table Style..." buttons, which open dialogs allowing you to perform the desired modifications.

Comment: Apologies, I am referring to the item that is generated when using the "Insert Table of Figures" feature in the References ribbon (I've updated the OP to clarify).

No contextual menu appears when formatting the Table of Figures, it is a bunch of field codes formatted as inline text.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Tables or Table Styles.The style involved here is the TOF style combined with the action of the TOC field.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon answers don't need titles. My answer doesn't have a title.